# Bind API Data in Angular?

Tags: angular, api

I am trying to bind Data which is coming from API, **Data is showing in the network but When I am trying to bind data it is giving me an error -**

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object
function'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

**API Data in Network**

```
 [{deliveryid: 0, frequency: "", ContactName: "Aa", Email: "aa@we.com",…},…]
     
//While expanding the response

{deliveryid: 0, frequency: "", ContactName: "Aa", Email: "aa@we.com"}
```

**.TS**

```
  public MyDigestEmailIdPrint = [];
  DigestEmailIdPrint() {
    var postData = {
    clientid: localStorage.getItem("storageselectedclient"),
  };

    this.article.DigestEmailIdPrint(postData).subscribe(
    (res) => { 
    if (res.message != "No Record Found") {
       this.MyDigestEmailIdPrint.push(res);
    }
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  }
);
```

}

**.HTML**

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let details of MyDigestEmailIdPrint">
    <td> {{details.ContactName}}</td>
    <td> {{details.Email}}</td>
    <td> {{details.frequency}}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
```

Comment: The problem is that you use `ngFor` for an object which, as the error states, is not an iterable. Your backend is not giving you an array, but an object.

Comment: So How will I change or fix this ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-iterate-object-keys-using-ngfor?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

`DigestEmailIdPrint` is a function and doesn't return anything.
Maybe you should use `MyDigestEmailIdPrint` in the `ngFor` but as pointed out in the comment, the data you get from the backend is not an array.

you can fix it like this:

```js
if (res.message != "No Record Found") {
    // use the spread syntax to create a new array and trigger change detection
    this.MyDigestEmailIdPrint = [...res.result];
}
```

Comment: error is gone but getting blank data, nothing is showing now on HTML page but data is in Network showing.

Comment: are you pushing the right data in the array? what is `res`?

also please stick to code conventions variables and functions shoudl be in camelCase starting with a lovercase

Comment: Pushing the res to MyDigestEmailIdPrint will create `[[{deliveryid: 0, frequency: "", ContactName: "Aa", Email: "aa@we.com"}, {deliveryid: 0, frequency: "", ContactName: "Aa", Email: "aa@we.com"}]]` something like this. That is not correct to data get in the view.

Comment: `res` is a response getting from API which is now `{code: 200, result: Array(5)}` and if we expand this the data will be shown `[{deliveryid: 0, frequency: "", ContactName: "Aa", Email: "aa@we.com"}, {deliveryid: 0, frequency: "", ContactName: "Aa", Email: "aa@we.com"}]`

Comment: @Zerotwelve also `this.MyDigestEmailIdPrint = res;` is array also as I have checked property see here - `{code: 200, result: Array(2)}
code: 200
result: Array(2)
 
0: {deliveryid: 0, frequency: '', ContactName: 'As', Email: 'as@nt.co.in', contactid: 5998}
1: {deliveryid: 0, frequency: '', ContactName: 'As', Email: 'av@nt.co.in', contactid: 93932}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[Prototype]]: Object`

Comment: well in that case you should do : ` this.MyDigestEmailIdPrint = [...res.result];`

Comment: @Zerotwelve this works! finally

Comment: @archana I corrected the code example. Please consider to accept and upvote the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to check the `res` type. It seems it must be an object and thats what the error is pointing to `NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

The error is not only linked to this, the question is when are you calling the API and does the view load till that time?

Solution 1:
If your response in the component is of different type, you can covert it to array.

Solution 2:
Check when the data is getting loaded into the view. You should know the lifecycle hooks to get the data at correct time to get things in component.

Solution 3:

```
if (res.message != "No Record Found") {
    // node need to push data to MyDigestEmailIdPrint
    // this.MyDigestEmailIdPrint.push(res); // add the data in the array
    this.MyDigestEmailIdPrint = res; // if res is an array it is fine to assign
}
```

Comment: Yes I am getting error while assign to `this.MyDigestEmailPrint = res;` is `Only arrays and iterables are allowed` Also noted that the data is res is like this `(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`

Comment: Have you checked the type of res?

Comment: thank you All I did is  `this.MyDigestEmailIdPrint = [...res.result];`

Comment: Yes, thats what solutions1 refers to. The res is of type object and you were getting results in result - this is because of the http response.

Comment: You don't even use spread operator to get the values, you can directly assign values: just a tip.